# Как выйти из приложения?

Tags: java, android

В моем приложении одна главная активность, и я добавляю в стек фрагменты при переходе (в последующих фрагментах схема такая же):

```
    NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,  fragment)
                    .addToBackStack("").commit();
```

Обработка нажатия:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LeagueStandingFragment lsf = new LeagueStandingFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("id", mLeague.getId());
        bundle.putString("leagueCaption", mLeague.getCaption());
        lsf.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_con‌​tainer, lsf)
            .addToBackStack("").commit();
    }
```

С обратной навигацией проблем нет, а вот выйти из приложения не получается. Как можно разрулить?

Comment: Тут уж Вам решать, какое действие будет выполнено при нажатии кнопки back: либо будет отображен предыдущий фрагмент, либо приложение закроется. Вам какое поведение нужно?

Comment: если это последний фрагмент в стеке - то закрыть приложение

Comment: А что происходит сейчас?

Comment: если совершать обратную навигацию, то на последнем фрагменте ничего не происходит (не удается выйти из приложения)

Comment: Добавьте код минимального воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: Дак, собственно, выше он и есть (код заключен в onClick(View view)).

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LeagueStandingFragment lsf = new LeagueStandingFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("id", mLeague.getId());
            bundle.putString("leagueCaption", mLeague.getCaption());
            lsf.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,  lsf)
                    .addToBackStack("").commit();
        }
    }

Comment: Нужен **минимальный** пример, на котором можно воспроизвести Вашу проблему (код активити и фрагментов).

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы переопределили метод onBackPressed ? В дефолтном случае при нажатии кнопки назад и отсутствии в бэкстеке транзакций FragmentManager'а должно произойти закрытие активити, если оно единственное - то и закрытие приложения соответственно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте метод `Activity#finish()`

Comment: вся проблема в том, что не понятно как прослушивать во фрагменте нажатие кнопки BACK, чтобы можно было отреагировать

Comment: Слушай нажатие в Activity. Там есть метод onBackPressed()

Comment: В своей Активности я переопределил onBackPressed() но он не срабатывает

Comment: Если не срабатывает, то, боюсь, без кода всей Activity я помочь не смогу.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Получилось организовать выход из приложения через метод dispatchKeyEvent
(KeyEvent event) (хотя, возможно, это и корявый способ, но он работает). Но 
погодя понял, что лучше предложить пользователю подтверждать сие действие через
 диалоговое окно. Нашел пример кода в просторах интернета, но при подключении 
опять перестал работать выход, и более того никакого диалогового окна не наблюдается???

public class FragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = "TESTING";
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return GreetFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        Log.i(TAG, "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)");
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
                        openQuitDialog();
                        finish();
                    }
                    mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    private void openQuitDialog(){ //метод предлагающий подтвердить выход
        AlertDialog.Builder quitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FragmentActivity.this);

        quitDialog.setTitle(R.string.quit);

        quitDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which){
                finish();
            }
        });

        quitDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which){
            }
        });
    }
}
```